# Error: unexpected string constant - a problem with letters with accents

Tags: r

I have a markdown file (utf-8), including such a command:

```
ds_ID <- ds_kk %>% distinct(Nyilvántartási_szám, .keep_all = TRUE)
Error: unexpected symbol in "ds_ID <- ds_kk %>% distinct(Nyilv�ntart�si_sz�m, .keep_all"
```

It runs well when I knit to PDF, but it gives an error if I try to run the chunk in RStudio.

There are characters with accents in a variable name. I may change the variable names to English names, but similar problem occurs with this command:

```
var <- "Nyilvántartási_szám"
Error: Incomplete expression: var <- "Nyilvántartási_szám"
```

Unfortunately, there is no option not to use these characters in the output.

The generated PDF is correct, but the issue makes developing and debugging very hard. Is there a setting in RStudio to fix this?

My only solution now is to change all those characters to English alphabet characters and change them back before the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Installing RStudio 2023.12.01 fixed it.